# How can I implement this twbs-pagination

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pagination

I am using [this plugin](http://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/#examples) to paginate my list items but I am confused about how to implement this to query to my table to pull and limit 10 or depending on my needs and display this inside in my `<ul>` tag.

Here is my sample.

Database.php

```
    class Database{

        protected $connection;


        public function __construct(PDO $connection)
        {
            $this->connection = $connection;
        }



        public function getData(){
            try{

                $cmd = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM names");
                $cmd->execute();
                $rows = $cmd->fetchColumn();

                $cmd=null;
                return $rows;

            }catch(PDOException $ex){

            }

        }
    public function display($start,$perpage){
        try{

            $cmd = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT name FROM names LIMIT ? , ?");
            $cmd->bindParam(1,$start);
            $cmd->bindParam(2,$perpage);
            $cmd->execute();

            $rows = $cmd->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $datali = '';
            foreach($rows as $r){
                $datali.='<li class="list-group-item">'.$r['name'].'</li>';
            }

            return $datali;


        }catch(PDOException $ex){

        }
    }


}
```

index.php

```
 require_once 'includes/config.php';
require_once 'includes/Database.php';

 $pdo = new PDO(HOST,USER,PASSWORD);
 $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$connectdb = new Database($pdo);

$rows = $connectdb->getData();

 $page = $_GET['page'];
 $per_page = 5;

$pages = ceil( $rows / $per_page );

if($page == 0)
   $start = 0;
else
   $start = ( $page - 1 ) * $per_page;

$data =  $connectdb->display($start,$per_page);
?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            var pages = '<?php echo $pages;?>';
            $('#mylist-ul').twbsPagination({
               totalPages: pages,
              visiblePages: 7,

          href: '?page={{number}}'
            });
        }); 

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
       <div class="wrapper">
         <?php echo $data ?>
        <ul class="list-group" id="mylist-ul"></ul>
       </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.twbsPagination.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Improved formatting and divided the html and javascript code to improve readability. Add a JSFiddle to your question to get a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to display. If you want to display data from a database, here is an example:

Let's say you have table with 10 rows of data in it.
First we need to query the db and get all data from the table

```
$result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM table");
```

Now we need to count the rows we got.

```
$rows = $result->num_rows;
```

Let's say we want 5 items to be displayed in each page.

```
 $per_page = 5;
```

We calculate the number of pages with

```
$pages = ceil( $rows / $per_page );
```

We will get 2 pages.

Now we will check the page we are on and set the starting point

```
    $page = isset( $_GET['page'] ) ? $con->real_escape_string($_GET['page']) : 0;
    $page == 0 ? $start = 0 : $start = ( $page - 1 ) * $per_page;
    $curpag = ( $start == 0 ) ? 1 : ( $start / $per_page ) + 1 ;
```

Now it's time to display data from the table

```
$result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $start, $per_page");
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)):
//display data in table/list/etc.
endwhile;
```

We add the pagination element with

```
<ul id="pagination" class="pagination-sm"></ul>
```

And finally we initialise the plugin

```
    <script>
var pages = '<?php echo $pages;?>'; //We store the number of pages in a variable to use it below
    $('#pagination').twbsPagination({
            totalPages: pages,
            visiblePages: 7,
            href: '?page={{number}}' //Very important!
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: does the (first,previous,next and last) buttons will work with that code also ?

Comment: yes. the plugin should work without problems with the code above.

Comment: I am confuse how can I get the return data and display it dynamically? Is this like a jquery.ajax() or this wil reload the page everytime I click the pagination button ?

Comment: You can use ajax to load content without reloading or changing page. My example uses GET variable to create pages based on amount of data you have in database. The first page will get results from db say with LIMIT 0,5(five results per page) then when you press on next page it will get with LIMIT 6,10 and so on.

Comment: do you have example in jquery.ajax ?

Comment: where does the variable $curpag will be use ?

Comment: it just calculates the current page. the plugin itself will calculate this value but if you don't want to use a class to highlight the navigation you can remove that line.

Comment: I updated my post, I still cannot get it work. Thank you in advance

Comment: What's the output? Do you get data outputted but the pagination is not working?

Comment: Get a var_dump for $data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81064/discussion-between-jemz-and-allkin).

Comment: @Allkin do you have any idea in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62427881/twbs-pagination-unable-to-load-new-page-data-in-datatable