# Twbs pagination unable to load new page data in datatable

Tags: ajax, spring, datatables, pagination

[image]

Hi I am working on pagination and found that unable to load data from twbs plugin when i click on the 2nd page. in fact the method is called from the ajax call but the datatable data is still the same. can someone tell me what to do to fill the table with the new data from the server.

have a look to the code in thymeleaf and spring boot.

```
     <table id=shortstorage class="table table-hover table-bordered dataTable no-footer" role="grid" aria-describedby="mtsdetails_info">
       <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="mtsdetails" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Sr.No.: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 43px;" aria-sort="descending">Sr.No.</th>
        <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="mtsdetails" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 41px;">Name</th>

        </thead>
         <tbody>
         <tr  role="row" class="odd" th:each="compregloop,incr : ${compregList}">
            <td th:text="${incr.count}" class="sorting_1"></td>
            <td th:text="${compregloop.companyname}"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
       </table>





<div class="text-center">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
        <ul id="pagination-demo" class="pagination-sm"></ul>
        </div>
        <div id="page-content" class="page-content">Page 1</div>
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = {
                  "page" : "2",
                  "size" :"10"
               }
        $('#pagination-demo').twbsPagination({
            totalPages: 14,
            visiblePages: 6,
            next: 'Next',
            prev: 'Prev',
            onPageClick: function (event, page) {
                //fetch content and render here
                $('#page-content').text('Page ' + page) + ' content here';
              var datapage = { "page":page};           
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/helloo/",
                    data:datapage,
                    contentType:'application/json',
                    success: function (data) {  
                  $('shortstorage').html(data)                 
                        }
                });
            }
        });
        </script>
```

The Controller is as folows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getcompany", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getCompany(Model model,HttpServletRequest request,Optional<Integer> pageSize, Optional<Integer> page){
        /// Getting Logged in user
        System.out.println("pageSize--------------------------------");
        System.out.println(page);
        //code added by sargam
        int evalPageSize = pageSize.orElse(INITIAL_PAGE_SIZE);
        int evalPage = (page.orElse(0) < 1) ? INITIAL_PAGE : page.get() - 1;


        System.out.println(evalPage+"--------------------------"+evalPageSize);

      Page<CompanyRegistration> compregPage = companyregister.findAll(PageRequest.of(evalPage, evalPageSize));
      List<CompanyRegistration> compregList = compregPage.getContent();
      model.addAttribute("compregList",compregList);
return "admin/company";
}

      @RequestMapping(value = "/helloo", method = RequestMethod.POST , consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public String mainWithParamhello(@RequestBody String data, Model model, HttpServletRequest request,
                RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

            System.out.println(data);
            System.out.println("Inside hello2");
             redirectAttributes.addAttribute("pageSize","10");
             redirectAttributes.addAttribute("page", "2");
            return "redirect:/getcompany";
        }
```

Comment: Do you have an html node with  `#pagination-demo` selector?

Comment: @joshuamabina yes updaing

Comment: It is standard procedure for a question to be cleaned up from meta-commentary, including the paragraph that you posted, because it is not constructive and not useful to future visitors. Users are free to comment and vote as they see fit, the disclaimer is unwarranted. Please stop bringing it back or the post may have to be locked unnecessarily.

Comment: You need to be doing something inside the `success` callback for changes to effect. Try `$('shortstorage').html(data)` to render whatever response you've received from the server.

Comment: @joshuamabina  not working with the code $('shortstorage').html(data)

Comment: @dhS, your intent is that `onPageClick`, fetch new data belonging to that page and update the page. So, we are making an ajax request which when it has successfully executed - we want to update the DOM. To do this, inside the `success` callback - we need to update the DOM.

If you have done this, please update the question.

Comment: @joshuamabina i have updated but still it is not working

Comment: @joshuamabina yes it is $('#shortstorage').html(data) it is working .... you can write as an answer here and thanks for it ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some few things to look at:**

1. You want to update your HTML document once it has loaded, hence `$(document).ready(...)`.
2. Decide on the node you want changes to take effect. Use jquery selectors to update the DOM on Ajax success i.e. `#shortstorage`.
3. Find a way to present your data from the Ajax response to a table. This example just dumps the output to the console and onto the page.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
      // Note: Run your scripts when the page has loaded.
      $(document).ready(function () {
        var data = {
          page: "2",
          size: "10"
        };
        $("#pagination-demo").twbsPagination({
          totalPages: 14,
          visiblePages: 6,
          next: "Next",
          prev: "Prev",
          onPageClick: function (event, page) {
            //fetch content and render here
            $("#page-content").text("Page " + page) + " content here";
            var datapage = { page: page };
            $.ajax({
              // type: "POST",
              // Note: using an API placeholder for fake responses
              url: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
              // data: datapage,
              // contentType: "application/json",
              success: function (data) {
                /**
                 * Note:
                 * 1. The node '#shortstorage' is where you want the changes to take effect.
                 * 2. You will need to find a way to present the data as a table before you render the page.
                 */
                $("#shortstorage").html(JSON.stringify(data));
                console.log(data);
              }
            });
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
```

---

Here's something for you to learn more about, [$( document ).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: how can i add excel export button and search bar to this twbs pagination..